# Informing clang that inline assembly reads a particular region of memory

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, clang, inline-assembly

GCC (all versions I can conveniently test) can be told that an inline assembly statement reads a particular region of memory (expressed as a pointer `p` and a size `n`) with this admittedly awkward construct:

```
asm ("..." : : "m" (*(struct { char x[n]; } *)p));
```

However, this does not work in clang (3.[45]), you get a hard error:

```
 error: fields must have a constant size: 'variable
      length array in structure' extension will never be supported
 asm ("..." : : "m" (*(struct {char x[n];} *)p));
                                    ^
```

Is there (ideally) a different construct which will produce the same effect in both compilers, or (failing that) a different construct which will produce the same effect in clang, only?

Note that in the case I care about, I insert no actual assembly instructions; the point of the construct is to direct the compiler not to delete an apparently-dead `memset`.  Thus, the "different construct" could perfectly well not involve inline assembly at all.  However, please suggest constructs which read *arbitrary* memory, or generate additional code, only if there is no alternative.  Also, DO NOT suggest `memset_s`, `explicit_bzero`, or similar; this is an attempt to *implement* a fallback for those functions without having to hack the compiler.

Full-scale demo program follows --

```
#include <string.h>

extern void foo(const char *a, const char *b, const char *c, char *d);

void bar(const char *x, char *y, size_t n)
{
  char w[16];
  char v[n];
  memset(w, 0x11, n);
  memset(v, 0x22, n);

  foo(w, v, x, y);

  memset(w, 0, 16);
  memset(v, 0, n);
  asm ("" : : "m" (*(struct {char _[n];} *)v));
}
```

-- as compiled by gcc 5.0 at `-O2 -S`, x86-64, CFI goo elided --

```
bar:
        pushq   %rbp
        leaq    15(%rdx), %rax
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        pushq   %r14
        andq    $-16, %rax
        movq    %rsi, %r14
        pushq   %r13
        movl    $17, %esi
        movq    %rdi, %r13
        pushq   %r12
        leaq    -48(%rbp), %rdi
        pushq   %rbx
        movq    %rdx, %rbx
        subq    $16, %rsp
        subq    %rax, %rsp
        call    memset
        movq    %rbx, %rdx
        movq    %rsp, %rdi
        movl    $34, %esi
        call    memset
        movq    %r14, %rcx
        movq    %r13, %rdx
        movq    %rsp, %rsi
        leaq    -48(%rbp), %rdi
        call    foo
        movq    %rbx, %rdx
        xorl    %esi, %esi
        movq    %rsp, %rdi
        call    memset
        leaq    -32(%rbp), %rsp
        popq    %rbx
        popq    %r12
        popq    %r13
        popq    %r14
        popq    %rbp
        ret
```

-- the goal is to get the *same number* of block memory fills out of clang.  Two is wrong, but four is also wrong.

Comment: It is not undocumentd for gcc. Not sure about clang, however. If the `memset` is unused, there is definively no reason to keep. What you are actually looking for is to use _barriers_ (aka _fences_). Look into `stdatomic.h` (since C11) for a standard way. Note that for a barrier, you just clobber `memory`, but that will still not include hardware barriers which handle caches/buffers correctly.

Comment: @Olaf Where did you see this documented? I honestly cannot remember where I learned it.

Comment: In the [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Extended-Asm)? The version for [gcc 5.2](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Extended-Asm) got the long pending overhaul (not sure, though, if the assembler interface is still the same). I had to find that on my onw, so not sure if this is ever tought in lessons. Still note this might not work as expected due to caches, write-buffers, concurrency, etc. You really should check atomics.

Comment: The gcc reference still requires the size of the memory region to be known *at compile time*, so you are relying on an unsupported, or at least undocumented, feature of gcc.

Comment: Since you're trying to implement a "fallback" why not implement your own version of memset using volatile pointers?

Comment: I would be cautious using that gcc construct for attempting to clobber memory.  While the docs still include it, my experience is that it not only [doesn't work](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2014-09/msg00342.html), it has unexpected (and undesirable) side effects.  How about `char buff[16] = "asdffdsajab"; char *p = buff; printf("%s\n", p); memset(buff, 0, 10); asm("#" : : "m" (*p));`?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd I'm sorry, could you be more specific? gcc 5.1.1 generates code that is not wrong, for your example (if I'm reading it correctly).

Comment: The code I posted above doesn't use the 'size trick,' which (as I mentioned) doesn't work correctly.  So I would expect it to work correctly.  Or do you mean that 5.1.1 correctly generates code for the example in the link I provided?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd The code in the link you provided is incorrect. It's annotated to *read* memory, but the assembly language is *writing* memory.  (The manual is indeed misleading.  An input is never a clobber.)  I get correct assembly output (for any value of `-DPAD`) from gcc-4.9 with the modified code here: http://pastebin.com/QSSC8JaX

Comment: @DavidWohlferd (It could be _better_ code -- it fails to notice that the initial stores to `c.a` and `c.b` are dead.  But it correctly reloads their values from memory in between the `asm` and the `printf`.)

Comment: @RossRidge (I'm sorry, I missed your comment until now) Use of volatile pointers would inhibit desirable optimizations.  For instance, in the "full-scale demo program", if I had applied the memory-use construct to `w` instead of `v`, I would still want the compiler to replace the `memset` with two `movq $0, [address]` instructions.

Comment: Since it's a fallback I'd be more concerned about getting something that works than something that's optimal. In any case you can write your own memset that uses 64-bit volatile stores that when inlined can result in a `movq $0, [address]` instruction being emitted. Though the performance difference isn't likely to be as big a you might expect.

Comment: @PeterCordes Your answer, in the question you marked this as a duplicate of, only discusses GCC. This question was specifically about clang/LLVM and explains how a technique for memory access in `asm` that works with GCC does _not_ work with LLVM. Please either investigate whether your (slightly different) technique also works with LLVM and add that to your answer over there, or unmark this as a duplicate.

Comment: @zwol: That was already on my TODO list, but I think I have tried this on clang in the past and found it does work, unlike the struct with flexible array member.